# Is it possible to export multiple select statement into one flat file?

Tags: db2

example:

EXPORT TO file.del of DEL ' select * from emp',
' select * from emp1'

this is not working . please advise. thanks

Comment: no. consider what'd happen if one select had an int in a particular field, and another select had a blob, and a 3rd had a varchar field... not a good idea to mix up formats like that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, because a file is understood to store the result of a single select.

If your two selects have the same set of columns, try to do a union select:

```
select * from emp union all select * from emp1.
```

In this way, you have only one select in the export, but it will contain the both tables. The query will be valid if the union can be done, when the columns have the same precision.